# How to read specific fields from mapped object in Hibernate

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, hql

I've got two entity objects in my database: UserEntity and ItemEntity and they're mapped with OneToMany relationship.
Here is my code:

UserEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   @GeneratedValue
   public int user_id;

   @Column(name = "userlogin")
   public String userlogin;

   @Column(name = "userpass")
   public String userpass;

   @Column(name = "name")
   public String name;

   @Column(name = "email")
   public String email;
   ....

   @JsonBackReference
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE },fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<ItemEntity> items;
```

ItemEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class ItemEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "title")
   public String title;

   @Column(name = "info")
   public String info;

   @JsonManagedReference
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
   private UserEntity user;
```

And now I'm trying to read all my Items from my database with specific fields from users that owns current item. I need only UserEntity name and email.

This code:

```
Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ItemEntity WHERE title = :title");
```

returns all fields from UserEntity also, because it's mapped, but I don't want that, because I'm sending that data as JSON, and someone can see all informations about user who own that item (like user login and password) in some dev tools like Chrome.
How to reach that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use DTO.

Covert your entities to DTO and then transform the DTO objects to 
json string.
In the DTO populate only those field that you want as part of your response.
This would make your design more clean.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's jitsonfire is suggesting, you can write a query like this

```
select name, email from ItemEntity WHERE title = :title
```

than get your results like

```
List<Object[]> result = query.list();
```

The object array will contain your columns, the list element will equal to rows, so you can do something like

```
for (Object[] tuple : result) {
  tuple[0]; //name
  tuple[1]; // email
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to ignore associated objects fields while selecting? I just need to join user name and email to my ItemEntity. But when I'm selecting any Item, it's automatically reads associated objects, which is fine, but in that one case I don't want that.